# ZIP a folder of files into multiple "stand-alone" ZIP files of maximum size

Tags: powershell, command-line, zip

I have the following problem: I'm writing a ***Powershell*** script that, after generating a lot of PDF files (each in a separate subfolder of a main folder), needs to zip them.

Here is the difficulty/problem:

> The destination where those ZIP files need to be unzipped (a Moodle website) has a **filesize limit of 50MB**, hence I need to generate **multiple ZIP files of this maximum size**.
> Each ZIP file, however, needs to be "standalone", i.e. it must be **unzipped by itself** (automatically by the website), without requiring the presence of the other files.

Here below is what I've tried so far:

- ***Direct Powershell approach:***

  ```
  Compress-Archive -Path "SourceFolder" -DestinationPath "Result.zip"
  ```

  This however only generates a single ZIP file (of "huge" dimension).
- ***7-Zip (command line tool) approach:***

  ```
  7za.exe" a -v50m "Result.zip" "SourceFolder"
  ```

  This correctly generates a lot of 50MB zip files, however of the form "Result.zip.001 , Result.zip.002" which, taken alone, cannot be uncompressed as individual zip files.

Can somebody suggest me a way to achieve my goal, i.e. to separate those files into individual ZIP files of size no larger than 50MB (of course the ZIP will be in general smaller than 50MB, since the PDF files have arbitary size, but all < 50MB for sure)? The result should look like:

> "*Result1.zip*" [49MB] , "*Result2.zip*" [47MB] , ... , *Result16*.zip [48MB], *Result17*.zip[7MB]

Thank you very much for any suggestion! :)

Comment: Use Get-ChildItems to get a list of filenames and then zip in groups.  You can assume compression rate is like 50% and then group files by size only zipping 500M (10x) to make sure you do not exceed the file size.  normally you would get compression around 5%-10% with text.  Images have much lower compression.  So depending on the data in the pdf you will get a wide range of compression rate.  You could add files one at a time to the zip.  When zipping one at a time I would use same zip utility when compressing and decompressing since not all zip tools are fully compatible with the zip spec.

Comment: This won't be trivial as you don't know in advance what the compressed size will be. You need to compress to know, so you could do a first run to determine which input file breaks the limit and then do a second run to actually create the archive, since you now know which files fit. The 50 MB fit well into memory, so the first run could be done in-memory, without creating an actual file (the .NET ZIP class `ZipArchive` can be constructed using an in-memory stream).

Comment: There are a number of different versions of the zip specification with optional requirements.  Not all zip utilities use the latest version and not all zip utilities implement the optional requirements.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers! The compression ratio varies significantly according to the PDF type (text vs. images of scan vs. text with pen comments vs. ...), so I can't "count" on a fixed rate. The idea of "compressing one by one" is very interesting, I'll try to implement it as an alternative to Mark_Albin's solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you look for something like this:

```
$filesFolderPath = "Path of where the PDFs are"
$archivePath = "Path to where the archive will be"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $filesFolderPath -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $fileName = $file.Name
    $filePath = $file.FullName
    Compress-Archive -Path $filePath -DestinationPath "$($archivePath)\$($fileName).zip"
}
```

This script will basically get the list of the files (assuming you only have PDFs in the location) and will archive each one.
If you want to be sure it only archives the PDFs please change this line:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $filesFolderPath -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".pdf" }
```

**UPDATE** (*changed the script to allow archive of multiple files if their combined size isn't over 50GB*):

```
$filesFolderPath = "Path of where the PDFs are"
$archivePath = "Path to where the archive will be"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $filesFolderPath -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".pdf" }
$filesToArchive = @()
$archiveSize = 0
$counter = 0

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $fileSize = [Math]::Round(($file.Length / 1MB), 2)
    
    # Check if the combined size of the files to be archived exceeds 50 MB
    if (($archiveSize + $fileSize) -gt 49) {
        # Create the archive if the combined size exceeds 50 MB
        $counter++
        Compress-Archive -Path $filesToArchive.FullName -DestinationPath "$($archivePath)\Archive-$counter.zip"
        $filesToArchive = @()
        $archiveSize = 0
    }

    # Add the file to the list of files to be archived
    $filesToArchive += $file
    $archiveSize += $fileSize
}

# Create the final archive if there are any remaining files to be archived
if ($filesToArchive.Count -gt 0) {
    $counter++
    Compress-Archive -Path $filesToArchive.FullName -DestinationPath "$($archivePath)\Archive-$counter.zip"
}
```

**UPDATE 2** (*added the warning and archiving of a single file if exceeds the 50MB size*).
All you have to do in with this update is to replace the foreach statement with the below code.

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $fileSize = [Math]::Round(($file.Length / 1MB), 2)
    
    # Check if the file is bigger than 49MB to archive it separately and write a warning
    if ($fileSize -gt 49) {
        $counter++
        Compress-Archive -Path $file.FullName -DestinationPath "$($archivePath)\Archive-$counter.zip"
        Write-Warning "The archive number '$($counter)' has a single file bigger than 50MB"
    } else {
            # Check if the combined size of the files to be archived exceeds 50 MB
        if (($archiveSize + $fileSize) -gt 49) {
            # Create the archive if the combined size exceeds 50 MB
            $counter++
            Compress-Archive -Path $filesToArchive.FullName -DestinationPath "$($archivePath)\Archive-$counter.zip"
            $filesToArchive = @()
            $archiveSize = 0
        }

        # Add the file to the list of files to be archived
        $filesToArchive += $file
        $archiveSize += $fileSize
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmmm I forgot that bit. What would you like to happen to the single PDF that exceed the 50MB? To be split in multiple zips? Or like just being skipped?

Comment: Hi, I've edited the answer. It should now be able to archive multiple files in a single archive (if their combined size isn't over 50MB) and archive the remaining files as separate archives.

If it's not that what you're saying please pardon me I'm not english mathertongue so I have hard time understanding your messages.
But, if I did get it right I won't mind upvotes :P

PS: I didn't add any block in case a PDF is over 50MB by itself, can add that too if required.

Comment: The script written should create as many zips as it can with combined files. For example if you have a folder with 130MB of PDFs (none individually over 50MB) it will create 3 archives only. I can always adjust the cade as I haven't faced this topic for the first time today, therefore I can help if it's required to add more and more details/functions. As it is right now it's written with a generic basis.

Comment: Hi, tried it and it works like a charm! :) No file is supposed to be greater than 50MB in my scenario (they usually are all between 0 and 10MB uncompressed). I would however say that, if it occours, I'll let the script print an errore like "Warning: Archive-17.zip contains a single file larger than 50MB)", which is easy to accomplish and lets the user know that something is impossible to achieve. Thank you very much! ;)

Comment: Hi Mattia, sorry I was having dinner :P. Please see the new update. You'd just need to replace the old foreach statement with the new one in **UPDATE 2** session. Please let me know if need more or could just upvote/accept the answer :).